# Reduce the number of times a class/function being called in a table

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a table on my website. Then I have a style that is being used in my `<td>`. However, I do not want to type the style out so many times in my code.

This is the function I declared.

```
const tdStyle = {
  paddingLeft: "35px",
  paddingRight: "35px",
  paddingBottom: "10px",
  paddingTop: "10px"
};
```

This is the code on my page.

```
<tr>
<td style={tdStyle}>NA</td>
<td style={tdStyle}>NA</td>
<td style={tdStyle}>NA</td>
<td style={tdStyle}>NA</td>
<td style={tdStyle}>NA</td>
</tr>
```

Is there any way that I do not have to type the style={tdStyle} so many times?

Comment: Maybe try using a loop, check out this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751951/generate-html-table-using-for-loop.
hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Make a component that has whose styles and then use it like given below.

```
const CustomTableCell = function(props) {
   return <td style={tdStyle}>{props.children}</td>;
}

<tr>
   <CustomTableCell>NA</CustomTableCell>
   <CustomTableCell>NA</CustomTableCell>
   <CustomTableCell>NA</CustomTableCell>
   <CustomTableCell>NA</CustomTableCell>
   <CustomTableCell>NA</CustomTableCell>
</tr>
```

Now you can change in one place and style is changed is everywhere.